# System.Text.Json problem that make swagger with .net core 3.1

Tags: json, .net-core, swagger

I am upgrading my 2.2 .net core web app to 3.1 build succeed but
swagger doesn't load and send message `Failed to load API definition.` and when I inspect the web request I found this error

```
Schema cannot be generated for type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[foonamespace.fooclass,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]] as it's not supported by the System.Text.Json serializer2at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.JsonSerializerDataContractResolver.
```

I have traced then I found the problem in this line of code

```
public Dictionary<Foo, Dictionary<string, string>> AdditionalData { get; set; }
```

Did anyone know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30524#issuecomment-524619972, but the author says specifically

> 'However it still cannot serialize a nested Dictionary such as
> Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> because System.Text.Json doesn't
> accept the inner type Dictionary<int, int>'

So in your code I think there is not possible. On .Net 5.0 will be available with system.text.json, but until then, the only solution is to use NewtonsoftJson.